# How to get an attribute's value, when it contains more keys/values, with XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, connection-string, xmldocument

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="Data Source=foo; Initial Catalog=bar;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

How do I get the value `foo` with the key `Data Source` ?

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(sectionXml);

// node
var node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/connectionStrings/add");

// attribute
var attr = node.SelectSingleNode("@connectionString").Value; // "Data Source=foo; Initial Catalog=bar;"
```

**Solution** (Thanks to Skeet)

```
var connectionString = nodeAttr_connectionString;
var builder = new System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder
{
    ConnectionString = connectionString
};

var dbserver = (string)builder["Data Source"];
var database = (string)builder["Initial Catalog"];
var user = (string)builder["User ID"];
var password = (string)builder["Password"];

session["CONN_STR_SERVER"] = dbserver;
session["CONN_STR_DATABASE"] = database;
session["CONN_STR_USERNAME"] = user;
session["CONN_STR_PASSWORD"] = password;
```

Comment: Well, it's a connection string - so why not get the whole connection string and then pass it to whichever connection string class is relevant? (Use an XML parser for the XML part, and a connection string parser for the connection string.)

Comment: The example is simplified. The real scenarie is that the user is trying to install a .msi, and the upgrade wizard (Advanced Installer) detects the customer already have a conn. Str. in my Custom Action. Hence, I want to insert the connection string parts into the inputs fields so user doesn't have to type it in again. And I need the parts to set the properties in the Custom Action.

Comment: I have a string now, so I could do some string code that gets the values, but I was expecting/hoping for XmlDocument to support this, now that it already can get the node and attribute.

Comment: Ahh now I get it. You mean I could just use a class like this `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`. Thanks just what I needed.

Comment: Yes, if ConfigurationManager knows how to parse connection strings. That's very .NET-specific, so I wouldn't expect XmlDocument to have any support - it's not part of XML.